# Getting indices of values in high dimension matrix

Tags: python, pytorch

I have  `tensorA` of size `10x4x9x2`, the other `tensorB` is of size `10x5x2` that contains values from `tensorA`. Now, how can i find the index of each element in `tensorB` in `tensorA`.
Example:
First 2 elements of  `TensorA`:

```
         [[[[ 4.,  1.],
          [ 1.,  2.],
          [ 2.,  5.],
          [ 5.,  3.],
          [ 3., 11.],
          [11., 10.],
          [10., -1.],
          [-1., -1.],
          [-1., -1.]],

         [[12., 13.],
          [13.,  9.],
          [ 9.,  7.],
          [ 7.,  5.],
          [ 5.,  3.],
          [ 3.,  4.],
          [ 4.,  1.],
          [ 1.,  0.],
          [ 0., -1.]],
          ...... so on
```

Fist 2 elements of `TensorB`:

```
   [[[ 2.,  5.],
     [ 5.,  7.],
     [ 7.,  9.],
     [ 9., 10.],
     [10., 12.]],
    
     [[ 0.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  2.],
     [ 2.,  5.],
     [ 5., -1.],
     [-1., -1.]],
```

Now in `tensorB` the first element is `[2,5]` included in the first `5x2` matrix (dimension `0`).
so the element should be matched against dimension `0` in  `tensorA`. And the output should be index
`0,0,2` since it is the 3rd element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the rows that are equal, sum along the last axis, and check that sum against the size of the searched tensor. Then the [nonzero](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nonzero.html#torch.nonzero) function will get you the indices you're looking for.

Since for the example tensors you have given, `TensorB[0, 0]` is `[2., 5.]`, that looks like:

```
((TensorA == TensorB[0, 0]).sum(dim=3) == 2).nonzero()
```

This will return a tensor of `[[0, 0, 2]]` if that is the only matching row. If you don't want to hard-code `2` (the size of the searched tensor), you can use:

```
((TensorA == TensorB[0, 0]).sum(dim=3) == TensorB[0, 0].size()[0]).nonzero()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it looks good, but what i am trying to do is get all the indices of `tensorB` without indexing a specific element.To explain more, i need to find the index of every element present in `tensorB` relative to `tensorA`. Would this be possible? or is it necessary to implement an explicit for loop ? Sorry I wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: I think you would need to implement a for loop for that

Comment: Yeah I thought so, but it will be very costly. So i will probably try to find an entirely new way to represent this. Thanks though !